# Pass a Groovy List as parameter to Build command in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, groovydsl

I want to be able to pass a List variable to the Build command in Jenkinsfile something like:

```
stage('test') {
  def listName = []
  build job: "/job/jobname", parameters: listName, propagate: false
}
```

When I try something like this I get an error:

hudson.model.PasswordParameterValue~PasswordParameterValue(name: String, value: String, description: String)}[], propagate?: boolean, quietPeriod?: int, wait?: boolean): java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildTriggerStep.setParameters() expects java.util.List but received class java.lang.String

Comment: That error appears to be referring to other code than what is in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Was able to get through this by using below code:

```
stage('test') {
   def listName = []
   listName .add([$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: "${listKey}", value: "${list.value}"])
   build job: "/job/jobname", parameters: listName, propagate: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `Map` to `parameters`:

```
stage('test') {
  def listName = [string(name: 'PARAM_NAME', value: "PARAM_VALUE")]
  build job: "/job/jobname", parameters: listName, propagate: false
}
```

Comment: But aren't you passing a `List` here?